# Using tail -F for monitoring huge file

Tags: linux, tail

I came across a requirement where I need to continuously monitor a live (appending) file for a predefined pattern (say a error message), I'm planning to use `tail -F [FileName] | grep "pattern"` & put it in some shell script to notify me. My concern is how its going to work for a huge file say 50 GBs in size, I want to understand how much system resources this kind of solution will consume. In short how tail works/handle a file in resource utilization perspective.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20256/is-it-fine-to-use-tail-f-on-large-log-files looks like exactly your problem.

Answer (score 3):

`tail` does not read the whole file. When it *can*, it starts at the end and then backtracks until it has reached the expected number of lines. However, it *does* read everything when it cannot seek, like reading from a pipe for example.

This might not apply to you, but keep in mind that `tail -f` tracks the *file descriptor* **not the filename**. So if you have for example log rotation, it will just stop, because the original file has stopped changing.